# What is the minimum number of exchanges required to arrange numbers in array such that all negative values occur before all positive ones?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we want to arrange the n numbers stored in any array such that all negative values occur before all positive ones. So how to find Minimum number of exchanges required in the worst case ?

Comment: N/2͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: @Bathsheba Just curious why N/2?

Comment: See this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition Doesn't explain why, but it sets the rabbit off.

Comment: [Learn how to create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can use this [approach](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segregate-0s-and-1s-in-an-array-by-traversing-array-once/)

Comment: @Ishpreet would you mind explaining to me why the method in your link is said to have O(n) when you iterate twice through the array? I don't quite get it.

Comment: @AhmedBajra The complexity is O(n) because the two loop in worst case iterate the array twice also `O(2n) = O(n)` therefore the overall complexity is `O(n)`. You can read more about [Two Pointer Technique](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/).

Comment: @Ishpreet Alright, thanks a lot

Comment: The worst case would be when the initial array has all positive values before all negative ones, and there is an equal number of each. For example `[-1,-2,-3,-4,4,3,2,1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two pointer approach.

1. Move all the negative numbers at first in-place and count the number of exchange required
2. Move all the negative numbers at end in-place and count the number of exchange required
3. Compare these number of exchange to get the minimum number of exchange.

Here is the C++ implementation:

```
    int minimumExchange(vector<int>& arr) {
        int result = INT_MAX;
        int countFirst = 0, countLast = 0;
        int n = arr.size();
        vector<int> tmp(arr); 

        int left = 0, right = 0;
        while(right < n) {
            if(arr[right] < 0) {
               swap(arr[left], arr[right]);
               if(left != right) countFirst++;
               left++;
            }
            right++;
        }

        arr = tmp;
        left = n - 1, right = n - 1;
        while(right >= 0) {
            if(arr[right] < 0) {
               swap(arr[left], arr[right]);
               if(left != right) countLast++;
               left--;
            }
            right--;
        }
        result = min(countFirst, countLast);
        return result;
    }
```

You can find working code [here](https://ideone.com/6THor1).

Time complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the size of array.